# Accesing Url Change of code

Tags: php, mysql

Currently on my website for special page I'm accessing the page like this :
mydomainname.com/torrents.php?parent_cat=Movie

But i want to access the page like this :

mydomainname.com/torrent.php/Movie **Or if Possible**

mydomainame.com/Movie

Here's the code that i'm using can any one help me with it.

```
    $addparam = "";
$wherea = array();
$wherea[] = "visible = 'yes'";
$thisurl = "torrents.php?";

if ($_GET["cat"]) {
    $wherea[] = "category = " . sqlesc($_GET["cat"]);
    $addparam .= "cat=" . urlencode($_GET["cat"]) . "&amp;";
    $thisurl .= "cat=".urlencode($_GET["cat"])."&amp;";
}

if ($_GET["parent_cat"]) {
    $addparam .= "parent_cat=" . urlencode($_GET["parent_cat"]) . "&amp;";
    $thisurl .= "parent_cat=".urlencode($_GET["parent_cat"])."&amp;";
    $wherea[] = "categories.parent_cat=".sqlesc($_GET["parent_cat"]);
}

$parent_cat = $_GET["parent_cat"];
$category = (int) $_GET["cat"];

$where = implode(" AND ", $wherea);
$wherecatina = array();
$wherecatin = "";
$res = SQL_Query_exec("SELECT id FROM categories");
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($res)){
    if ($_GET["c$row[id]"]) {
        $wherecatina[] = $row["id"];
        $addparam .= "c$row[id]=1&amp;";
        $thisurl .= "c$row[id]=1&amp;";
    }
    $wherecatin = implode(", ", $wherecatina);
}
```

Comment: Look up .htaccess rewrites. There are a lot of examples on Stack Overflow itself. Use the search.

Comment: Also, unrelated: There is **no more support** for `mysql_*` functions, they are [**officially deprecated**](https://wiki.php.net/rfc/mysql_deprecation), **no longer maintained** and will be [**removed**](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-connect.php#warning) in the future. You should update your code with [PDO](http://php.net/pdo) or [MySQLi](http://php.net/mysqli) to ensure the functionality of your project in the future.

Answer (score 2):

You can use url rewrite to do that;

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^/(.+)$ torrent.php?parent_cat=$1
```

Put this in your .htaccess file. You can refer [here](http://www.smashingmagazine.com/2011/11/02/introduction-to-url-rewriting-2/) for more detail about url rewrite

By doing this, when you go to url `mydomainname.com/torrent.php/Movie` it will act like `mydomainname.com/torrents.php?parent_cat=Movie` at the backend

Comment: Thankx for the Info
But I want that when user click on link of the website user should go to that url
mydomain/torrents.php/Movie 
But its still going to same Url

But still going to